# Please show steps using Gaussian Elimination to solve X for a set of modular linear equations

Tags: linear-algebra, modular-arithmetic, gaussian-elimination

There is a linear system of 4 equations in field $Z_p$ with 4 unknowns $k_1$, $k_2$, $x_1$, $x_2$. The other variables s, r and h are known.

Please show me all the steps using Gaussian Elimination or any other method to get from the four modular linear equations below to solve for X. I know the answer for X but I want to be shown so I can understand all the steps how you can use Gaussian Elimination or any other method to get to the answer for $x_1$.

These are the four modular linear equations:

$s_1k_1 - r_1x_1 = h_1$ (mod p)

$s_2k_1 - r_1x_2 = h_2$ (mod p)

$s_3k_2 - r_2x_1 = h_3$ (mod p)

$s_4k_2 - r_2x_2 = h_4$ (mod p)

(in the equations above h is congruent)

to:

$x_1 = \frac{(h_1r_2s_2s_3 - h_2r_2s_1s_3 -h_3r_1s_1s_4 + h_4r_1s_1s_3)}{r_1r_2(s_1s_4 - s_2s_3)}$

where operations including division are in the multiplicative group $Z_p$.

So to clarify I would like you to show me how to use Gaussian Elimination or any other method and all the steps involved to get to the above given answer for x1 please.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Thanks for editing and clarifying the question for me